# How can I loot a body stuck under the landscape?

Tags: state-of-decay-2

I'm playing State of Decay 2 on Windows (via Steam).

> **tl;dr:** My follower died and was zombified. When I found him, he was glitched underneath a rock. My new follower killed him, but the body is still underneath the rock. Is there a way I can get under the rock to loot it?

---

I went out with a follower and we did a NPC quest. (I will call my dead companion "Bob".) Long story short, a huge horde of zombies spawned around us, and Bob was killed. I finished the quest (escorting the NPC to safety), then picked up a new companion from my base ("Charlie") and went back to find Bob's body to get his loot. I know that in this game, followers who die will hang around the area of their death as a zombie, and to get their equipment you first need to kill the zombie and then loot the body.

After a bunch of time wandering around the area where the Bob had been killed and killing any zombie I ran into, I started hearing weird growling noises coming from a rock. The minimap showed an enemy target at the area of the rock, but there were no zombies in sight. Eventually I climbed on top of the rock, and the minimap target overlapped mine, so I presume the zombie was somehow spawned underneath the rock. As I scouted away, I lost sight of my current follower (Charlie) and then noticed that the minimap was showing Charlie in combat with the underground zombie. Eventually Charlie killed the zombie -- and now there's a new symbol on the minimap showing a coffin.

So clearly what happened is that Bob died and came back as a zombie. The game erroneously spawned him underneath this rock in the landscape. While Charlie and I were scouting the area, the game had the two NPCs fight, which both glitched them under the landscape. Now Bob's body is ready to be looted ... but I can't get to it.

I tried using the 'stuck' radio option, which reset my position but didn't since I was never stuck under the landscape. After I moved far enough away, Charlie was teleported next to me like stuck NPCs do.

How can I get to this lootable body? Is there a console with debug commands I can access? (eg something similar to Fallout's `tlc`)

[image: Screenshot]

This is the rock in the screenshot. You can see on the minimap that the coffin indicator is directly ahead of me; but it's *under* the rock and not on top of it so I can't access it.